# Replace the line containing the Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have an input string containing multiple lines(demarcated by \n). I need to search for a pattern in the lines and if its found, then replace the complete line with empty string.

My code looks like this,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*@@.*$");  
String regex = "This is the first line \n" +  
               "And this is second line\n" +  
               "Thus is @@{xyz} should not appear \n" +  
               "This is 3rd line and should come\n" +  
               "This will not appear @@{abc}\n" +  
               "But this will appear\n";  
Matcher m = p.matcher(regex);  
System.out.println("Output: "+m.group());
```

I expect the response as :

```
Output: This is the first line       
        And this is second line  
        This is 3rd line and should come  
        But this will appear.
```

I am unable to get it, please help, me out.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others mention turning on multiline mode but since Java does not default to DOTALL (single line mode) there is an easier way... just leave the ^ and $ off.

```
String result = regex.replaceAll( ".*@@.*", "" );
```

Note that the issue with either this or using:

```
"(?m)^.*@@.*$"
```

...is that it will leave the blank lines in.  If it is a requirement to not have them then the regex will be different.

Full regex that does not leave blank lines:

```
String result = regex.replaceAll( ".*@@.*(\r?\n|\r)?", "" );
```

Comment: As another poster points out, adding \n? to the end will replace without leaving blank lines... though should be expanded to \r?\n? if you think you might get DOS-style line endings.

Comment: Thanks, PSpeed, Can you please give the regex, that returns the string without leaving the blank lines.

Answer (score 5):

In order to let the `^` match the start of a line and `$` match the end of one, you need to enable the multi-line option. You can do that by adding `(?m)` in front of your regex like this: `"(?m)^.*@@.*$"`.

Also, you want to keep grouping while your regex finds a match, which can be done like this:

```
while(m.find()) {
  System.out.println("Output: "+m.group());
}
```

Note the regex will match these lines (not the ones you indicated):

```
Thus is @@{xyz} should not appear 
This will not appear @@{abc}
```

But if you want to replace the lines that contain `@@`, as the title of your post suggests, do it like this:

```
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "This is the first line \n" +  
                      "And this is second line\n" +  
                      "Thus is @@{xyz} should not appear \n" +  
                      "This is 3rd line and should come\n" +  
                      "This will not appear @@{abc}\n" +  
                      "But this will appear\n";  
        System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(?m)^.*@@.*$(\r?\n|\r)?", ""));
    }
}
```

Edit: accounted for *nix, Windows and Mac line breaks as mentioned by PSeed.

Comment: Thanks Bart, 
But is there a way to get the string, without the lines that matched the pattern.(I need that.)

Comment: Yes, I showed how to do that in my `replaceAll(...)` example.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a multiline option in Java, check the docs. There is one in C# atleast, I think that should be the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the JavaDoc on the Matcher.matches() method:

```
boolean java.util.regex.Matcher.matches()
Attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern. 

If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods. 

Returns:
true if, and only if, the entire input sequence matches this matcher's pattern
```

Try calling the "matches" method first.  This won't actually do the text replacement as noted in your post, but it will get you further.